# JS array reduce and update neighboring replicas

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

The input is an array containing three types of strings: letter L with attached digit, letter R with attached digit, and letter D with attached digit. These strings may repeat. The task is to write a function that will take the neighboring Ds and reduce them to one D with updated digit of Ds that were present before. **Notice that only neighboring Ds should be reduced and counted.** Examples of the output I want:

```
input: ['D1', 'D1', 'L1', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1', 'R1']
output: ['D2', 'L1', 'D3', 'R1']

input: ['R1', 'D1', 'L1', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1', 'L1', 'R1', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1']
output: ['R1', 'D1', 'L1', 'D4', 'L1', 'R1', 'D3']
```

Apparently my function doesn't work for two main reasons: splicing the array while looping (I'm trying to get rid of excessive Ds), and I force the function to look outside the scope of the array at the last iteration (arr[i+1].charAt(0) === 'D'). I can't overcome these issues.

```
function reduceD(arr) {
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            let str = arr[i];
            if (arr[i].charAt(0) === 'D' && arr[i+1].charAt(0) === 'D') {
              arr[i] = 'D' + (Number(str[1]) + 1);
              arr.splice(i+1, 1); 
          }
        }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answer: If you want to iterate over an array while deleting elements, do it backwards so you don't miss any elements. Here's a fixed version of your code and one with a simple loop that IMHO is easier to understand (and a lot easier than the `Array.reduce` function in the other answer for beginners)

I agree with the other answer, though, that `Array.reduce` is the way to go for more experienced programmers who know how `Array.reduce` works.

```js
// the fixed version of your code
function reduceD(arr) {
  // iterate backwards to make the splice possible
  // also note how the loop does never reach i == 0 but stops at 1 instead
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let str = arr[i];
    if (arr[i].charAt(0) === 'D' && arr[i - 1].charAt(0) === 'D') {
      arr[i - 1] = 'D' + (Number(str[1]) + 1);
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

// the IMHO simpler way of creating a new array
function buildingNewArray(arr) {
  let out = [];
  let dsFound = 0;
  for (const elem of arr) {
    if (elem.charAt(0) === 'D') {
      dsFound++;
    } else {
      // there is no D in the current element
      if (dsFound > 0) {
        // add all found Ds as one
        out.push('D' + dsFound);
        dsFound = 0;
      }
      // always output the current element to the output
      out.push(elem);
    }
  }
  // we're done with the loop but there might be some Ds to output
  if (dsFound > 0) {
    out.push('D' + dsFound);
  }

  return out;
}


const arr1 = ['D1', 'D1', 'L1', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1', 'R1'];
const arr2 = ['R1', 'D1', 'L1', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1', 'L1', 'R1', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1'];
console.log(buildingNewArray(arr1));
console.log(buildingNewArray(arr2));
console.log(reduceD(arr1));
console.log(reduceD(arr2));
```

Comment: Thank you, so cool and clever how you fixed my code using backwards iteration. The easier for me to understand it as I'm a beginner. Big thanks!

Comment: Your second solution buildingNewArray I also like it, I starred at it for a while to finally get the logic behind it. What I missed before is the trick to set the Ds count back to zero after pushing it into new array, as you did with dsFound = 0 inside the loop. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Please use Array.reduce function.

```js
function reduceD(arr) {
    const result = arr.reduce((total, val) => {
        if(total.length === 0) 
            total.push(val);
        else {
            const last = total[total.length - 1];
            const newValue = last.charAt(0) + (Number(last.slice(1)) + 1);
            last.charAt(0) === val.charAt(0) ? total.splice(total.length - 1, 1, newValue) : total.push(val);
        }
        return total;
    }, []);
    return result;
}

console.log(reduceD(['D1', 'D1', 'L1', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1', 'R1']));
console.log(reduceD(['R1', 'D1', 'L1', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1', 'L1', 'R1', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the array to a new array, if the current item is not the correct character, or the last item in the accumulator (`acc`) doesn't start with the correct character, push the current item. Otherwise, increment the number of the last item.

```js
const isChar = (char, item) => !!item?.startsWith(char);
const incItem = item => `${item[0]}${+item.substring(1) + 1}`;

const reduceD = (char, arr) => 
  arr.reduce((acc, c) => {
    if(!isChar(char, c) || !isChar(char, acc[acc.length - 1])) acc.push(c); 
    else acc[acc.length - 1] = incItem(acc[acc.length - 1]);
  
    return acc;
  }, []);

console.log(reduceD('D', ['D1', 'D1', 'L1', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1', 'R1'])); // ['D2', 'L1', 'D3', 'R1']

console.log(reduceD('D', ['R1', 'D1', 'L1', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1', 'L1', 'R1', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1'])); // ['R1', 'D1', 'L1', 'D4', 'L1', 'R1', 'D3']
```